# Mongodb find documents using filters

Tags: mongodb, typescript

In my case I have a MongoDb model as follows

```
product: {
  _id: "5e464a0d746fe294a788d134",
  productName: "Mobile Phone",
  brand: "Samsung", //Type is string
  ...
}
```

let say I have several brands like Samsung, Apple, Huawei, Sony etc. 
I send "brands = [Apple, Sony]" to the API filter param and I need to return all the documents with matching the brands that I send.

What I did so far is

```
let productList = await this.model
        .find(
            {
                brand: {
                    $or: [
                        { $eq:  [brands]}
                    ]
                }
            }
        )
        .skip(filterOptions.skip)
        .limit(filterOptions.limit)
        .sort(filterOptions.sortBy);
```

But it doesn't return the expected result. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply use `db.collection.find({ brand: { $in: brands } })`

Comment: @sAntd use $in not $eq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
db.collection.find({ brand: { $in: brands } })
```

this answer posted by [Wernfried Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit)